# Oracle Forms 10g - 'NULLS' is not accepted

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Oracle `Forms 10g` - `'NULLS'` is not accepted.

In program unit(PL/SQL Code) I use `NULLS FIRST` and its throwing error.

> ```
> Encountered the symbol NULLS
> ```

```
select line_id 
from oe_order_lines_all 
where rownum <5 
order by line_id NULLS FIRST;
```

kindly help

Comment: Share your PLSQL program.

Comment: select line_id from oe_order_lines_all where rownum <5
     order by line_id NULLS FIRST;  It works in SQL developer but in oracle forms - compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with forms, but a simple workaround (if it works) is to modify the `order by` clause. For example, assuming the line id's are positive, or at least non-negative, you could

```
order by nvl(line_id, -1)
```

Comment: Great .. That's what I was looking for .. I didn't thought of that.  You are Awesome :) ,

Answer (score 1):

The flavour of PL/SQL and SQL used in Forms is different and somewhat older than the one available in the database. Being able to run code on the database does not mean it will run without changes in Forms. Analytic functions is an example of a newer SQL feature which is missing in Forms. But you can always put your code into a PL/SQL package in the database and call it from your forms code.

Comment: Hey Sers.. that's a good Idea. But still there should be some way to handle this scenario right ?

Comment: +1 You are quite right, but it does seem surprising that Forms 10G would not support "nulls first", which has been valid in SQL for as long as I can recall (Oracle 6.0!)

Comment: Forms always lagged behind the database. I remember when PL/SQL had this same problem :)